# Accessing samba shared files over internet

Tags: linux, ssh, network-shares, samba, smb

I am trying to access my samba share over internet. I can already access it via ssh and I have opened the 445 port but I cannot find the linux command line to access it.

Let's say I have the following:

- Alessio as local account
- website.ddns.net as public ip
- multimedia as smb shared file
- 192.168.1.150 as local ip

how do I access it via a command line?

On nautilus I have the following: smb://raspberrypi.local/multimedia.
I have the samba shared filesystem on OMV5 installed on a rpi3 connected to my router. In the router I have the port 22,80,445 opened.

Answer (score 0):

Samba is not safe by default to share over internet. I suggest you to use sftp or sshfs if both of your systems are linux.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).